# Получение элемента вне класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

браузер на pyqt5. В ответ на сигнал QWebEngineView(обычный класс который унаследовал его, в нем изменена функция createWindow) urlChanged нужно изменить адрессную строку и положить туды url. Но вот вопрос: как получить доступ к адресной строке?(QLineEdit)

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, а зачем?

Comment: @andreymal пишу прогу на pyqt5, и мне нужно получить этот объект из другого класса

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос "зачем", к сожалению

Comment: Ну объект-то редактируется элементарно через `объект.bar = 456`

Comment: Так у вас готовый объект или класс? Вы уж определитесь там, что вам нужно-то

Comment: И всё-таки зачем? Вы хотите очень странную вещь, которая в большинстве языков программирования технически невозможна

Comment: В Си это как раз невозможно, через указатели вы хрен найдёте, в каком месте кода хранится это 123. А если и найдёте, то не измените, потому что память может быть защищена от записи операционной системой. А зачем, вы не написали, вы лишь написали «мне нужно изменить объект» — а зачем изменить, я так и не понял

Comment: Да, это решит [проблему молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710) и мы сможем вам рассказать, как решить задачу **правильно**, а не как вам приспичило :) (А может и не сможем. Это как повезёт)

Comment: @andreymal браузер на pyqt5. В ответ на сигнал QWebEngineView(обычный класс который унаследовал его, в нем изменена функция createWindow) urlChanged нужно изменить адрессную строку и положить туды url. Но вот вопрос: как получить доступ к адресной строке?(QLineEdit). Если требуется, могу создать репу на гитхабе и положить туда все исходники

Comment: @GENKY, взяли и полностью изменили вопрос сделав мой ответ неадекватным :(

Comment: Какие-то сложные ответы. Почему бы не передать ссылку на адресную строку в `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Какие-то сложные ответы. Почему бы не передать ссылку на адресную строку в __ init __

спасибо тебе, ув. [eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri)!

Answer (score 2):

Пример по браузеру с адресной строкой:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWebEngineView, QApplication, QUrl, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.url_le = QLineEdit('http://qt-project.org/')

        self.go_pb = QPushButton('Go')
        self.go_pb.clicked.connect(self._on_load_url)

        url_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        url_layout.addWidget(self.url_le)
        url_layout.addWidget(self.go_pb)

        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.urlChanged.connect(self._on_url_changed)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(url_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_load_url(self):
        self.view.load(QUrl(self.url_le.text()))

    def _on_url_changed(self, url: QUrl):
        self.url_le.setText(url.toString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После клика будет загрузка, а сайт укажет новый адрес и в адресной строке это поменяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня отдельный собственный класс с qwebengineview, а адрессная строка,  в другом классе, в котором вся графика. Я могу только при создании класса с qwebengineview, передать в аргументы адрессную строку.

Comment: Есть два метода: 1) Передайте в ваш webengineview ссылку на другой класс с адресной строкой. И когда захотите что-то поменять обратитесь к объекту другого класса и к его адресной строке 2) Тот же способ, что 1, но через сигналы-слоты. Например, соединяете сигналом urlChanged из webengineview к слоту `setText` виджета той адресной строки. Если же вам не нравится идея работы одного с подвиджетами другого класса, то у вашего класса создаете метод и его к сигналу подключаете, а в методе работаете с адресной строкой Кст, если приложите в вопрос ваш код, то мог бы наглядно показать что имел ввиду :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 123

class Other:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def set_foo_bar(self, value):
        self.foo.bar = value


foo = Foo()
print(foo.bar)  # 123

other = Other(foo)
other.set_foo_bar(456)

print(foo.bar)  # 456
```